# How to return a value from an inner interface in method?

Tags: java, android, interface

I have these two methods declared:

```
private Result mResult;

private void setResult(Result result){
    this.mResult = result;
}

private Result getResult(){
    new Executor(new OnResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Result result) {
            setResult(result);
        }
    }).execute();
    return mResult;
}
```

Im using an interface while an AsyncTask is executing. What my problem is, is that I want to return the Result object of the **onResult** method as an object to the **getResult()** method.

As shown above, I tried to set it through a setter, but it seems that this is not working.

How can I succeed that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You simply can't do that. You could use Handler/LocalBroadcast/EventBus to pass a message in an async way. Another way would be to create a class that extends AsyncTask, then ,when process is finished call a callback method to up the modifications or new data

Comment: Have you tried changing the mResult identifier to `static`? And just call it inside the `onResult` like so: `mResult = result;` ? If that doesn't work, what about using an interface?

Comment: You have an asynchronous callback, and you want to get its result by a blocking getter.
I think you should review your code logic. What do you really want to achieve ?
I think your problem might be simply solved by implementing an interface

Comment: Yeah, but how can I succeed that, and then grab the result object from the interface?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here. The bad one is to wait until the new thread will finish. let's don't do that). the better way is to use a callback for:

```
public static interface OnResultCallback {
    void onResult(Result result);
}

private void getResult(final OnResultCallback callback){
    new Executor(new OnResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Result result) {
            setResult(result);
            callback.onResult(result);
        }
    }).execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I understand, but how can I wait till the thread is finished?

Comment: And how to get the Result then from the Callback interface?

Comment: @Kanellis attache please full source code of the `async task`. I'm not completely sure how you use it alongside with `executor`

Answer (score 1):

You could provide an instance of `OnResultListener` as part of the constructor of your `AsyncTask`, which the caller has to implement. E.g.

```
private Result mResult;
private OnResultListener mListener;
private void setResult(Result result, OnResultListener listener){
    this.mResult = result;
    mListener = listener; 
}


private Result getResult(){
   new Executor(new OnResultListener() {
       @Override
       public void onResult(Result result) {
          if (mListener != null) {
              mListener.onResult(result);
          }
          setResult(result);
       }
    }).execute();
   return mResult;
}
```

or you could directly provide `mListener` to `new Executor`

Comment: I dont quietly understand your way..you call the setResult method using one parameter, but you have declared two..

Comment: You had the first parameter. Its purpose eludes me.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomOnResultListener extends OnResultListener{
Callback callback ;   
public CustomOnResultListener(Callback callback){}
   this.callback =callback; // use this callback to send result
 }
public interface Callback{public void onCallback(Result result);};
```